# HackerRank Implement Queue using two stacks Solution

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, stack, queue

[Challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/queue-using-two-stacks/problem)

Problem Statement - Implement a Queue using two Stacks

I implemented `dequeue()` in \$O(1)\$ at the cost of `enqueue()` in \$O(n)\$

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

struct Queue{
    stack<int> s1,s2;

    int dequeue(){
        int x = s1.top();
        s1.pop();
        return x;
    }

    void peek(){
        cout<< s1.top()<<"\n";
    }

    void enqueue(int data){
        while(!s1.empty()){
            s2.push(s1.top());
            s1.pop();
        }

        s1.push(data);

        while(!s2.empty()){
            s1.push(s2.top());
            s2.pop();
        }
    }
};


int main() {
    int t; cin>>t;
    Queue q;

    while(t--){
        int k; cin>>k;
        switch(k){
            case 1:
                int x; cin>>x;
                q.enqueue(x);
                break;
            case 2:
                q.dequeue();
                break;
            case 3:
                q.peek();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There are 15 test cases. This code runs properly for the first 5 test cases then I get a 'Time Limit Exceeded' message for the rest of test cases.

This means the complexity of my program is too much.

So I tried reversing it, I made enqueue() as \$O(1)\$ and dequeue() as \$O(n)\$ but even that did not change anything.

What should I do to reduce time complexity of this code?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Algorithmic complexity for combined operations

Containers are interesting elements in most programming languages: they have an internal state, namely their elements and therefore their size.

This introduces an additional state compared to usual algorithmic asymptotical complexity analysis. For example, a naive implemented `std::vector::push_back` will yield \$\mathcal O(n^2)\$ complexity if `push_back` increases the capacity only by one:

```cpp
// pseudo-code, also very bad performance and no error handling, do not use!
void vector::push_back(T value){
    if(_size == _capacity) {
         // has to move all elements and is therefore O(n)
         reserve(_capacity + 1);
    }
    _data[_size++] = value;
}
```

While trivial, this code has a severe problem: we have to copy all elements in *ever* iteration. If we use `push_back` in a loop, we end up with a quadratic complexity.

The real `push_back` has therefore some tricks up in its sleeves, as the standard dictates that it will have \$O(1)\$ *amortized* complexity. More about that later in this review.

However, this small introduction should give you a hint about the central flaw in your current approach.

### A hidden quadratic term

> I implemented `dequeue()` in \$O(1)\$ at the cost of `enqueue()` in \$O(n)\$

For this task, it's much more important to see the cost on both functions for \$k\$ enqueued elements, not a single one.

So let's envision the queue `{1,2,3,4}`. How many steps do we need?

```
to enqueue 1: 
  1. put `1`  in `s1`
to enqueue 2:
  1. move `1` from `s1` to `s2`           
  2. put `2` in `s1`
  3. move `1` from `s2` to `s1`
- to enqueue 3:
  1. move `1` from `s1` to `s2`
  2. move `2` from `s1` to `s2`
  3. put `3` in `s1`
  4. move `2` from `s2` to `s1`
  5. move `1` from `s2` to `s1`
- to enqueue 4:
  1. move `1` from `s1` to `s2`
  2. move `2` from `s1` to `s2`
  3. move `3` from `s1` to `s2`
  4. put `4` in `s1`
  5. move `3` from `s2` to `s1`
  6. move `2` from `s2` to `s1`
  7. move `1` from `s2` to `s1`
```

We see that the \$n\$th element will take \$2(n-1)\$ swaps. Therefore, if we insert a total of \$n\$ elements into our queue, we end up with \$\mathcal O(n^2)\$ to complete all enqueues.

We need to do better.

### A better queue with two stacks

So let's get back to the drawing board. What do we need?

1. We need to enqueue
2. We need to dequeue
3. We need to peek.

None of those terms indicates that we need to have all data in *one* stack. So first of all, we need to use **better names**, because `s1` and `s2` are pretty bland and non-descriptive:

```cpp
class Queue{
    stack<int> in;
    stack<int> out;

    void flip();   // < new

public:
    void enqueue(int);
    int  dequeue();
    int  peek();
};
```

I'll implement the methods outside of the class declaration to keep the code segments short, but you're free to place them inline again. Note that I switched from a `struct` to a `class`, because its `Queue`s job to make sure that `in` and `out` are handled correct; no one else should be able to change them.

What will we use `in` and `out` for? Well, as long as we have elements in `out`, we will use them for `dequeue` and `peek`. And whatever gets `enqueued` gets pushed right ontop of `in`, no questions asked.

The critical part is how to get an element from `in` to `out`, right? I let you think about that for some paragraphs, but you may also stop here and try it yourself; the declaration above contains a clue.

So, let's have a look at my proposal for the definition of `enqueue()`, `peek` and `dequeue()`:

```cpp
void Queue::enqueue(int value) {
    in.push(value);
}

int Queue::peek() {
    if (out.empty()) {
        flip();
    }
    return out.top();
}

int Queue::dequeue() {
    if (out.empty()) {
        flip();
    }
    int value = out.top();
    out.pop();
    return value;
}
```

Note that the additional private method `flip` is yet missing. However, I will state the envisioned complexity:

- enqueue is \$\mathcal O(1)\$ (amortized)
- dequeue is \$\mathcal O(1)\$ (amortized)
- peek is \$\mathcal O(1)\$ (amortized)

Intrigued? Great. So let's check `flip`:

```cpp
void Queue::flip() {
    while(not in.empty()) {
        out.push(in.top());
        in.pop();
    }
}
```

`flip` takes all elements in `in` and moves them to `out`. It thereby changes the order of the elements, so that the `top` in `in` will be the last to get moved out of `out`. Note that we call `flip` only when `out` is empty.

### Amortized analysis

*"Wait a second! That's \$\mathcal O(n)\$" I hear you say. And that's completely correct. However, how often do we need to call `flip`? Or, rather more important, **how often do elements get moved**?

The answer on the latter question is: exactly one time from `in` to `out`. At no point will they move back. The number of `flip` calls is much trickier, though, but it doesn't really matter. At worst, `flip` may need to flip all elements, for example if we use it as follows:

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    queue.enqueue(i);
}
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    queue.dequeue(); // first dequeue will flip
}
```

However, only the **first** dequeue will flip. All others will yield the element immediately. Therefore, if we enqueue \$n\$ elements and then dequeue all of them, we end up with `dequeue()`'s complexity as:

$$\frac{n\mathcal O(1) + \mathcal O(n)}{n} = \mathcal O(1).$$

We can compare that with your original variant:
$$\frac{n\mathcal O(n)}{n} = \mathcal O(n)$$

This is why your code exceeded the time limit.

## Further review on code

There are some other findings that don't need as much detail as the algorithm, but nonetheless can be improved:

- there are some unused includes (`<vector>`)
- [`using namespace std` is considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
- the names are misleading or at least not self-descriptive
- `peek()` usually returns a value and does not print
- the `struct Queue` should have been a `class Queue` due to the assumption that the elements are always in the right order.

Comment: Thanks. This answer dives in a lot deeper than the question. I am reading the links you provided. Later I used simple arrays to implement stacks rather than STL stack and the solution got accepted.

Comment: You might consider `std::vector` as an alternative to an array-based stack, . `std::stack` usually uses `std::vector` underneath. You might as well cut out the middle-man and use `std::vector` and `std::vector::reverse` to make sure that `push_back` won't allocate for the first ~3k elements or so.

Answer (score 9):

You might want to look at the [discussion tab](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/queue-using-two-stacks/forum) for why the code is timing out. Basically the code should reverse the input stack only when `peek()` or `dequeue()` is called, and not in `enqueue()`.

The rest of this answer is a review of the code as posted and it ignores the fact that HackerRank supplied some of the code, such as the includes and the `using namespace std`. Issues such as readability and maintainability are beyond the scope of HackerRank, but are considerations when writing good code.

### Avoid Using Namespace `std`

If you are coding professionally you probably should get out of the habit of using the `using namespace std;` directive. The code will then more clearly define where the objects/functions are coming from (`std::cin`, `std::cout`). As you start using namespaces in your code, it is better to identify where each function comes from, because there may be function name collisions from different namespaces. The object `cout` you may override within your own classes. This [Stack Overflow question](//stackoverflow.com/q/1452721) discusses this in more detail.

### Magic Numbers

Numeric constants in code are sometimes referred to as [Magic Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), because there is no obvious meaning for them.
The values for the variable `k` are defined by the problem, but it might be better to use symbolic constants rather than raw numbers in the `switch` statement. That would make the code easier to read and maintain. C++ provides a couple of methods for this; there could be an `enum`, or they could be defined as constants using `const` or `constexpr`. Any of these would make the code more readable. There is a discussion of this [on Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com/q/47882).

### Use Descriptive Variable Names

The variable names `s1` and `s2` are not very clear, and if they weren't in `std::stack` declarations I really would have no idea what they were. Since this is a queue problem it might be better to name them `front` and `rear` to represent what they are used for. It is very hard to maintain code with variable names such as `s1`, `s2`, `q`, `t`, `k` and `x`. As an example, for `k` I might use `queryIndex`.

Since the restrictions on all input indicates there will be no negative numbers, it might be better to use `unsigned` rather than `int`.

### Prefer to Not Include What Isn't Necessary

It is much better to only include what is necessary in a source file. There are currently 6 headers included, but only two are necessary (`<iostream>` and `<stack>`) for this implementation. Including `<cstdio>` is bad because it might lead the programmer to use C I/O functions rather the C++ ones. Including only what is needed improves compile times, because the contents of all the includes are part of the compilation. It could lead to other problems if you are implementing your own class rather than using a C++ container class (such as `std::queue` from `#include <queue>`).

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stack>
```

### Prefer One Declaration Per Line

Maintaining code is easier when one can find the declarations for variables. It would be easier to find where `s2` is declared if it was on a separate line.

```
    std::stack<int> s1, s2;
```

Versus

```
    std::stack<int> s1;
    std::stack<int> s2;
```

Remember you may win a lottery and may not be the one maintaining the code.

The same reasoning applies to 2 statements on a line, such as

```
    int k; cin>>k;
```

Answer (score 7):

One thing not already mentioned in the answers: When you have a member function which does not change the state of the object, then make it `const`:

```
// no
void peek(){ cout<< s1.top()<<"\n"; }

// better
void peek() const { cout<< s1.top()<<"\n"; }

// even better
int peek() const { return s1.top(); }
```

Comment: Excellent addition, completely overlooked that.